# What is the reason that Russia is much richer even though they are corrupt at LDC-level?

Tags: russian-federation, economy, corruption

- LDC = Least Developed Country.

Russia and Pakistan both sit at the bottom of the CPI's [2022 corruption perception index](https://www.transparency.org/en/cpi/2022). Russia's position is 137/180. [Russia also faces economic sanctions.](https://www.atlanticcouncil.org/blogs/econographics/russia-sanctions-database/) However, [the Russian economy is projected to overtake the UK and German economies in 2023](https://biz.crast.net/russias-economy-is-expected-to-overtake-germany-and-britain-in-2023/).

Pakistan's position is 140/180, and it is almost bankrupt.

**Why is a difference?**

Is it **only** because Russia is an energy producer? I guess, not as [Angola is also an energy producer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_Angola) and its economy is not growing as fast as Russia. Also, Russia's GDP per capita is much higher than that of Angola.

Russia, Pakistan, and Angola have similar corruption levels (the superimposition of graphs is mine):

[image]

However, the Russian economy is far superior in terms of performance:

[image]

**So, what is the reason that Pakistan/Angola are damn poor but Russia is much richer even though they are corrupt at similar levels?**

Comment: I could talk about the assumption that corruption causes poverty, and the lack of representativity of the CPI's surveys of elites, but the more important point is that Russia's GDP per capita is less than a third of that of the UK. Russia just has more people.

Comment: Your quote 'Russia economy overtakes Germany and the UK' is grossly misleading. What they actually mean is that the projected annual change in Russia in 2023 is higher than in Germany and the UK (after Russia suffered a massive crash last year).

Comment: The "overtake Germany and the UK" quote is **so** in need of qualifiers that I'm voting to close on grounds that this post is trying to discredit a side.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, because corruption and economic growth have a reverse correlation, but are not in a direct causal relationship.

- Denmark ranks #1 in the CPI and #9 in GDPPC.
- Ireland ranks #10 in the CPI and #1 in GDPPC.
- Uruguay ranks #14 in the CPI and #63 in [GDPPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_GDP_(PPP)_per_capita).
- The UAE rank #27 in the CPI and #5 in GDPPC.

From the CPI's page, you can find their methodology: https://images.transparencycdn.org/images/CPI_2022_Methodology.zip

This methodology includes a list of sources:

1. African Development Bank Country Policy and Institutional Assessment 2020
2. Bertelsmann Stiftung Sustainable Governance Indicators 2022
3. Bertelsmann Stiftung Transformation Index 2022
4. Economist Intelligence Unit Country Risk Service 2022
5. Freedom House Nations in Transit 2022
6. Global Insight Country Risk Ratings 2021
7. IMD World Competitiveness Center World Competitiveness Yearbook
   Executive Opinion Survey 2022
8. Political and Economic Risk Consultancy Asian Intelligence 2022
9. The PRS Group International Country Risk Guide 2022
10. World Bank Country Policy and Institutional Assessment 2021
11. World Economic Forum Executive Opinion Survey 2021
12. World Justice Project Rule of Law Index Expert Survey 2021
13. Varieties of Democracy (V-Dem v. 12) 2022

Many of those have stopped reporting on Russia. From reading through the ones that still do, e.g. the World Bank, they assess factors such as:

> (a) accountability of the executive to oversight institutions and of
> public employees for their  performance;  (b) access of civil society
> to information on public affairs; and  (c) state capture by narrow
> vested interests.”

To take one example, Russia has hardly any access of civil society to information on public affairs. But that's not an immediate barrier to economic growth. It's going to be a problem later down the line, for instance it makes the country much less attractive for FDI (foreign direct investment). FDI isn't the only development model that works, though.

The causal relationship between corruption and economy is indirect. In some countries, corruption can be caused by extreme poverty. In others, it can be caused by a political coup that overtakes the country by narrow interests. In some, it's culturally ingrained.

Finally, the perceptions can be subjective, e.g. some cultures tend to automatically trust their government, deservingly or not, others to automatically distrust, deservingly or... *well, pretty much always deservingly*.